# How much should I pay for a simple android app

Tags: price, software, fixed-price

I want my own quiz application on android, with just about 50 multiple choice questions.

How much should I pay to the developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you provided:

- Your app does just ask 50 multiple choice questions,
- has no user accounts or logins,
- does not validate or
- visualize or
- send this data anywhere,
- the questions never change
- and I naughtily assume you are going to publish it on the play store...

If these really are the parameters of the app(**winkwink!**), congratulations, you got yourself a cheap one.

- One hour for hacking down 50 Strings,
- One hour for coding and clicking together the UI
- Some time to make it look nice
- Some time to write descriptive/meta texts for the Play Store
- Some time to publish it, set things up.

This is comfortably doable in a day, half that if you don't like your contractor.